# Centering a div in css error or am I just doing it wrong?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have read around and all the tutorials I have found told me to do the same basic things.  However when I do this
Code I am useing:

```
.center{
width: 50%;
margin: 0px auto;
}
```

It takes the six items I have and centers them but doesn't put 3 on a line(I am using bootstrap with 6 span3 divs that should make 3 and 3).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bootstrap you need to follow this pattern:

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="span3 offset2"></span>
         <div class="span3"></span>
         <div class="span3"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="span3 offset2"></span>
         <div class="span3"></span>
         <div class="span3"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Are you trying to center the 3 spans?

Comment: I don't mean to ask stupid questions but how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .center{   
     position: relative; /*add this */
     float: /*left, right, both; use what you want*/
     width: 50%;
     margin: 0px auto;
 }
```

to your .center class